# ELIMINAR ARCHIVOS GENERADOS INTELLIJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Quería saber si hay alguna forma de eliminar los archios auto generados por intelliJ de un proyecto. Me refiero a los archivos .idea y .iml. O si hay alguna manera de que el github lo ignore. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el directorio principal del repositorio debería haber un archivo llamado .gitignore, y si no, se puede crear. Ese archivo tiene las rutas que git debe ignorar. En particular, para esto, basta con añadir al archivo una línea con:

```
.idea/
```

De esa forma ignorará todo el directorio `MiProyecto/.idea/`